# Parameter sysctl fs.quota.syncs

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I can't find a clear answer about the fs.quota.syncs parameter

What is it responsible for and is it a configuration parameter or a counter?

The value is different on different servers. After reboot - value 0. Which hints that it is a counter.